# Radio Buttons within a PHP while loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm displaying data from MySQL DB in a tabular form in HTML and PHP.
Here, each 'order' has its own 'status' i.e., every row should have 2 radio buttons to change its status. Though it displays all the radio buttons, the problem is I'm unable to select a radio button FOR EACH ROW, I can only select single radio button FOR ALL THE ROWS!

```
<?php
$con3 = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_usrnm,$mysql_pass, "customer") or die("Ouch!");
$sql_query = " SELECT * FROM order_info WHERE deptt='".$_SESSION['deptt']."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con3, $sql_query);
if (!$result) {
printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con3));
exit(); }   

        echo '<table border="0px">';    
    echo'<th>Product</th><th>Type</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Order Status</th>';

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ //Tabular Data
  $type=$row["type"];
      $make=$row["make"];
      $quantity=$row["quantity"];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['make'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";
    echo '<td><cb><input type="radio" name="status" value="not approved">Not Approved<br>
<input type="radio" name="status" value="approved">Approved</cb></td>';
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You keep outputting the same form elements in each iteration. There's literally nothing different about them. You need to change their name so they are unique.

Comment: Radio buttons are automatically grouped by `name`.  Give each group of radios different `name`s.

Comment: so do I make an array for `name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change the `name` of the input. I am guessing that you also have a database field called `id`, so I'll use that in the example:

```
echo '<td><cb><input type="radio" name="status[' . $row['order_id'] . ']" value="not approved">Not Approved<br>
<input type="radio" name="status[' . $row['order_id'] . ']" value="approved">Approved</cb></td>';
```

Also when you process your form, you can get the value by using for example `$_POST['status'][2]` for the row with id=2. You can easily loop the `$_POST['status']`.

Comment: `order_id` is an auto-increment variable, how do I access the specific id?

Comment: Simply change `id` to `order_id` (see edited answer). Since you use `SELECT *` in your query, it should be accessible via the `$row` array.

Comment: Another question, how do I store value of these radio buttons in my database i.e., in the field `status`?

Answer (score 0):

Add a number, I recommend the internal id of the "order", to the end of the "name" value, like

`name="status123"`